# how to find and add a string to a file in linux

Tags: linux, shell

How can I check a file for a string if missing the string automatically add it for example
Input

Input file test.txt

1. this is a test text for testing purpose
2. this is a test for testing purpose
3. this is a test for testing purpose
4. this is a test text for testing purpose

I would like to add "text" to all the lines

Desired Output

1. this is a test text for testing purpose
2. this is a test text for testing purpose
3. this is a test text for testing purpose
4. this is a test text for testing purpose

Is it possible? many thanks in advance

Hi guys thanks for all the help, for my case is not that simple. I wont know which line will be different and in the middle string it will not only have a single string. i will give a clearer case

Input file test.txt

1. Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Role: Viewer Dept: IT
2. Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Dept: IT
3. Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Role: Viewer Dept: FINANCE
4. Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Dept: FINANCE

Desired output file test2.txt

1. Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Role: Viewer Dept: IT
2. Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Role: - Dept: IT
3. Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Role: Viewer Dept: FINANCE
4. Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Role: - Dept: FINANCE

So those that are missing "Role:" will be added "Role: - ", hope this clear things out, thanks in advance again

Comment: It depends. [`sed 's/test for/test text for/g'`](http://ideone.com/XtsHZa) works for your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you formalized your problem a little bit: it is unclear what is the criteria for determining where the 'Role:' text should be. Then the implementation will be a matter of re-phrasing it in a regular expression substitution. E.g., if you want to always have 'Role' before second ':', then you could do it like:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*?:.*?)(?:\sRole)?:/$1Role:/' test.txt
```

If you wanted to show where the substitution is made with '-', then slightly more complicated expression would be:

```
perl -pe 's/^([^:]+:[^:]+)(?<!Role):/$1 Role: -/' 1.txt
```

Output:

```
Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Role: Viewer Dept: IT
Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Dept Role: - IT
Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Role: Viewer Dept: FINANCE
Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Dept Role: - FINANCE
```

It's not exact output as in your example but again, you'd need to formalize where exactly you want 'Role: -' to be added. I took second ':' just as an example.

Exact output could be achieved by way simpler code:

```
perl -pe 's/Dept:/Role: - Dept:/ unless /Role:/' 1.txt
```

Output:

```
Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Role: Viewer Dept: IT
Group: IT_DEPT,VIP Role: - Dept: IT
Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Role: Viewer Dept: FINANCE
Group: FINANCE LOAN VIEWER Role: - Dept: FINANCE
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if the string before "Dept:" does not have "Role:" add "Role: -", but the way that you propose is quite helpful as well thanks

Comment: I've added another example in the response above.

Comment: what I actually wanted is the "Role: - " to be added before "Dept:" not "Dept Role: -"

Comment: That's what I'm telling you - you need to formalize what you want. It will actually help tremendously when you'll try to find bugs in your substitutions:). Anyways, added a simple example in the response above.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest, but this will do for your requirements:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "test" && $(i + 1) != "text") {
            $i = "test text"
        }
    }
    print $0
}' input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

for your current example, this awk one-liner should work:

```
awk '$5!="text"{$5="text "$5}7' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f 
this is a test text for testing purpose
this is a test for testing purpose
this is a test for testing purpose
this is a test text for testing purpose

kent$  awk '$5!="text"{$5="text "$5}7' f
this is a test text for testing purpose
this is a test text for testing purpose
this is a test text for testing purpose
this is a test text for testing purpose
```

Comment: This is helpful, but for my real case is not really usable. thanks anyway